# Как установить размера текста в зависимости от размера экрана?

Tags: android, textview, текст

Весь экран занимает TextView. 
В нем выводиться текст примерно такого формата:

```
<string name="text">
"Здравствуйте`введите сюда код`, девочки!
Здравствуйте, мальчики!
Смотрите на меня в окно.
И мне кидайте свои пальчики, да!"
</string>
```

Как сделать так чтобы размер текста автоматически менялся в зависимости от размера экрана? Чтобы не было переносов на новую строку как показано на скриншоте ниже[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы размер вашего текста менялся в зависимости от размера экрана, нужно добавить свойство к textView:

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
```

будет что-то типа такого:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

так же вы можете установить минимальный, максимальный кегли и шаг:

```
android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
```

итоговая картина:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp" />
```

[документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) по вашему вопросу.

Comment: а это нормально работает на api 15+?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, the library provides support to Android 4.0 (API level 14) and higher.

Comment: Это я тоже читал, но на практике у меня не завелось. Вот и спрашиваю про работу на api 15+

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, а как вы определили что не работает? может размер текста и размер экрана такие, что вы не заметили изменения размера? или вы на разных устройствах тестировали?

Comment: Конечно на разных: 5,7, 10"

Comment: не работает похоже - This is not an error; the application will simply ignore the attribute. хотя на сайте у гугла пишет что поддерживается, странно